# Dynamic number of rows containing dynamic number of input fields vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I trying to create a form which would have a dynamic number of steps. An additional step can be added on click of a button. Inside that step, there are a couple of `input` fields but also few more `button`s to create more `input` fields.

For example, there are the `title` and `description` `input`s but also link to `Add a Video` which would create another `input` field and would change that link to `Remove the Video`.

All these steps have to create one array of objects where each object might contain slightly different properties. I'm new to vue and it's very confusing.

```
<div v-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="index">

<input type="text" v-model="row.title">
<input type="text" v-model="row.description">
<div v-show="row.video">
    <input type="text" v-model="row.video">
</div>
    <a v-on:click="addVideo(index);" style="cursor: pointer">Add Video element</a><br>

<a v-on:click="removeElement(index);" style="cursor: pointer">Remove</a>
</div>
<div>
    <button class="button btn-primary" @click="addRow">Add Step</button>
</div>
```

and my functions:

```
addRow () {
  this.rows.push({
    title: '',
    description: '',
    file: {
      name: 'Choose File'
    }
  })
},
addVideo (index) {
  this.rows[index].video = ' '
  this.$forceUpdate()
},
removeElement (index) {
  this.rows.splice(index, 1)
}
```

or code at this link: http://jsbin.com/punekukayu/1/edit?html,js,output

At this point I don't know how could I **remove** the `Add Video element` link from that step and I suppose this is the bad practice approach here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `v-if` and `v-else`:

```
<a v-if="input.video === null" v-on:click="addVideo(index);" style="cursor: pointer">Add Video element</a>
<template v-else>
    <input type="text" v-model="input.video">
    <a v-on:click="removeVideo(index);" style="cursor: pointer">Remove Video element</a>
</template>
```

And you would add `video` as null by default, so you don't need to call `$forceUpdate`:

```
addRow() {
  this.inputs.push({
    one: '',
    two: '',
    video: null                     // added
  })
},
addVideo (index) {
  this.inputs[index].video = '';    // changed
},
removeVideo (index) {
  this.inputs[index].video = null;  // added
},
```

[**Updated JSBin here**](http://jsbin.com/rucuquyevi/edit?html,js,output).

---

If I may suggest, you should pass each `input` directly to `addVideo` or `removeVideo` (instead of `index`). I think it makes the code simpler: http://jsbin.com/pucohawuje/1/edit?html,js,output - But I do understand this could be a matter of taste, so I'm leaving it just as suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! that's great tips